# About "sudo go run main.go"

Tags: go, path, sudo

I use Go in my Ubuntu 16.04, and I set `GOPATH`, `GOROOT` and run simple code successfully.

Now I want to capture network packet by "gopacket", but it needs sudo /root permission. I excute command: `sudo go run main.go`, it echo error:

> "exec: go: excutable file not found in $PATH"

I googled it and I edit file `/etc/sudoders` and change line `"Defaults env_reset"` to `"Defaults !env_reset"`, but it not work...

Can you help me?

Comment: Your issue is not connected with go lang

Answer (score 12):

Your environment variables are not set for your root user. Don't try to run `sudo go run ...`, instead build the binary without sudo, e.g. `go build` or `go install`, and then execute the binary with `sudo`.

Let's say you're in the folder of `main.go`, assumed it's called `mycapt`:

```
go build
sudo ./mycapt
```

Or:

```
go install
sudo $GOPATH/bin/mycapt
```

Answer (score 8):

`sudo -E go run main.go` may work for you.

Here is what you can get about `-E` option from `man sudo`

```
-E, --preserve-env
   Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve
   their existing environment variables. The security policy may return
   an error if the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.
```