# Why can't "go get" find $GOPATH when "go env" shows it's set correctly?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm attempting to get go version go1.6.4 darwin/amd64 installed on my Macbook Pro.

I can't seem to download remote packages with 'go get' despite having the $GOPATH set.
$ go env

```
GOARCH="amd64"  
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"  
GOHOSTOS="darwin"  
GOOS="darwin"  
GOPATH="/Users/Bryan/go"  
GORACE=""  
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"  
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"  
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"  
CC="clang"  
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"  
CXX="clang++"  
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

$ ls /Users/Bryan/go

```
total 24  
drwxr-xr-x   6 Bryan  staff   204 May 23 12:13 .  
drwxr-xr-x+ 73 Bryan  staff  2482 May 25 11:20 ..  
-rw-r--r--@  1 Bryan  staff  8196 May 24 15:11 .DS_Store  
drwxr-xr-x  32 Bryan  staff  1088 Mar 28 14:21 bin  
drwxr-xr-x   3 Bryan  staff   102 Mar 28 14:21 pkg  
drwxr-xr-x  10 Bryan  staff   340 May 25 11:18 src
```

Bryan@Bryans-MacBook-Pro Thu May 25 12:23:24 ~/go/src/skincarereview
$ sudo go get

```
Password:  
package google.golang.org/appengine: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath  
package google.golang.org/appengine/datastore: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
```

Comment: In general, you should't build software with `sudo`, and it definitely isn't required with Go.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [About "sudo go run main.go"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40374434/about-sudo-go-run-main-go/40374998#40374998).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$GOPATH` is set in your user `$PATH`, but you are envoking `go get` using `sudo` which has its own `$PATH` different from yours.

To illustrate, try `sudo go env` and you will see the difference.

You probably shouldn't be using `sudo go get` anyway though.

Comment: Worth noting, if you're using `sudo` because of permissions errors on your `$GOPATH` or `$GOROOT` (I was running into this problem for a while, and was using `sudo` as a hack to fix it), `chmod` (or `chown`) your `$GOPATH`/`$GOROOT` so it works properly instead.  `sudo` _really is_ just a hack to solve this issue.